# How does TCP work on an actual system

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, ip

I know all the details about tcp and udp and how they provide transport level support for applications but what I am interested in is how tcp/udp is actually implemented in a host system. Is it via a number of system/function calls or is it a daemon process running which continually takes data from its buffers and encapsulates before writing to device driver buffer?

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty broad question and it's going to depend what system you're using and what facility the applications are using.

But in general, unix/windows use sockets to communicate using tcp.  You send/receive data using a socket by doing system calls (there are a few different ones).  So it's implemented in the kernel not through a userspace daemon on these systems.

Answer (score 0):

It is a module that runs in kernel space as part of a networking protocol stack. Applications communicate with it via system calls, e.g. Socket(), connect(), accept(), recv(), send().